# Modifying the default list form with CSR in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

I'm a new SharePoint developer working in a 2016 on-prem environment. I have been exploring options for modifying list forms using the Standard Client-Side Rendering render mode, but I'm at a loss for how to accomplish simple tasks within the `SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides` method.

On the `NewForm.aspx` page, I would like to swap the Description field (which displays underneath each input field) and the Title field (the label in the left column) in each row of the default form. I can access these data fields within the `ctx` object of the method in question, but I can't seem to write a solution that would accomplish swapping them.

I have been following along with Andrei Markeev's articles on the topic ([SP CSR List Forms](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/610259/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms) and [SP CSR List Forms + Layout](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1039724/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms-p)) but haven't got working code to show for it. Here is me logging the two fields I am concerned with swapping:

```js
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  OnPreRender: function(ctx) {
    console.log(ctx.ListSchema.Field[0].Description);
    console.log(ctx.ListSchema.Field[0].Title);
  }
});
```

What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so sure about your requirement 'swap', while you could use jQuery to update the DOM structure.

Here is demo to change Field Comment render(from last to second).

[image]

CSR result.

[image]

Insert script editor webpart into new form and insert the script into it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
            OnPreRender: function (ctx) {
                //console.log(ctx.ListSchema.Field[0].Description);
                //console.log(ctx.ListSchema.Field[0].Title);
                $("nobr:contains('Comment')").closest('tr').insertBefore($('table.ms-formtable>tbody>tr:nth-child(2)'));
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi @Lee_MSFT, thanks very much for that example, it is very helpful.